# Optimistic locking in Redis-rb does not seem to be working

Tags: ruby, redis

Spent hours trying to get a test case working. From my understanding, after the watch block is started, if that key is changed between then and the exec time, the multi block should do nothing.

```
redis = Redis.new
thread = Thread.new do
  redis.watch("test_case") do 
      sleep 20  
      redis.multi do |setup|
       redis.set "test_case", "foo"
      end
  end
end
```

and then during the 20 second sleep in IRB

```
redis.set "test_case", "bar"
```

The result is "test_case" => "foo". It should be "bar" because the watch should not allow execution of the multi statement. I have also tested this in redis-cli and the commands work as expected.

Comment: I don't see any Redis commands within multi block (that are supposed to be queued and executed atomically if the transaction succeeds) - it is not clear what you're actually testing...

Comment: Even if I put a redis command there in multi, it would not work. I tried doing it without a block (which is now deprecated) {redis.watch "test"; redis.multi; redis.set "test", "foo";} IRB returns "OK" instead of Queued and then EXEC does not work.

Comment: Could you add a reproducible example, please?

Comment: I have done as you requested. See the edits above.

Comment: I figured out my problem. Should have been more obvious but alas. I have a module that defines "redis" as redis = Redis.new. So every time that I gave a command to Redis, a new object was being created. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was I had a module defining:

```
def redis
 @redis = Redis.new
end
```

Everytime I called redis, a new object was made.